# Debugging with PyCharm terminal arguments

Tags: python, pycharm

I have been using PyCharm for a bit so I am not an expert.

How I normally ran my programs was with the terminal like so:

`program.py -t input1 -t1 input2`

I was wondering how can I debug this?

For other programs I wrote, I did not have any arguments so debugging was simply setting break points and pressing debug.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Menu: `Run` -> `Edit configurations` -> `"+" (add new config)` -> `Python`.

Script name: `program.py`

If you need to debug a script from installed packages, such as `tox`, you can specify the full path too. For example:
Script name: `/home/your_user/.envs/env_name/bin/tox`

Above `/home/your_user/.envs/env_name` is a path to virtual environment containing `tox` package.

Script params: `-t input1 -t1 input2`

Comment: You seem to be pretty good at using PyCharm I have another question if you dont mind helping =D http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27952638/usr-bin-env-python3-4-within-pycharm-project

Comment: @DrumM not sure I understand you. Can you clarify and give an example what you're trying to do ?

Comment: easy: like you would do on a command line, adding variables to it: e.g.:
./program.py $LIST_OF_FILES
It's just a pain in the *** if the list of files you want to test, you always have to change the config...

Comment: @DrumM - there is a tick to open confuguration screen on each launch.
That's one option.
Option 2: get output of your shell command inside python app you're debugging.
Option 3: specify the facilitator as the launch app. It will gather required data and then run the code you're trying to debug

Comment: Note that arguments with spaces in them should be wrapper in double quotes, _not single quotes_. This tripped me up for a little bit.

Comment: I can't see python and the edit configuration section!

Comment: @basilisk What IDE are you using? And what do you see ?

Answer (score 41):

Just an image-based representation of the answer.

1. Click on the `Run` menu click `Edit Configurations...`

   [image]
2. Select `+` in top right corner and select `Python`

   [image]
3. Provide the name, absolute path of the script or select the script by clicking three dots (green arrow), script parameters, and python interpreter.

   [image]

Comment: In case its not clear, the parameter 1 and parameter 2 are not place holders but actual values.

Answer (score 1):

It was almost correct but just needed little correction with full script path.

Menu: `Run->Edit configurations->"+" (add new config)->Python`.

Script name: `path + /program.py`

Script params: `-t input1 -t1 input2`

Answer (score 0):

I guess PyCharm Community Edition is different or something. Once inside of the configurations, what I had to do was:

1. Enable Python parameters:
   [image: modify options -> parameters]
2. Then you can enter your parameters:
   [image: enter parameters]