# #!/usr/bin/env python3.4 within PyCharm project

Tags: python, pycharm

I copied a project online and it contains

`#!/usr/bin/env python3.4`

When running on the terminal this is fine. But I want to debug with PyCharm. I am getting the error

`ImportError: No module named queue`

Because in python 3 the module is called `Queue`

I don't think PyCharm is recognizing #!/usr/bin/env python3.4` or it is not running the program in python 3. How can I fix this issue?

***EDIT:***

I changed the interpreter to python 3.4 but the same error is occurring =/ The settings have been changed but I noticed that the auto correct leads to Python 2 methods. Not sure how I can fix this.[image]

[image]

Comment: What environment is set for the project? See https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/configuring-python-interpreter-for-a-project.html

Comment: The answer in @Andy's comment is good, you should specify interpreter.