# Why does script run with command line arguments on PyCharm fail?

Tags: python, pycharm, command-line-arguments

On Pycharm CE, I want debug a script with arguments.

Following [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27952331/debugging-with-pycharm-terminal-arguments), I set `script parameters` to `-p /Users/heloman/code_base/cvg_c*.cpp`. Ran with this new added configuration and get `Skipping input '/Users/heloman/code_base/cvg_c*.cpp': Can't open for reading`

However, command `./script.py -p /Users/heloman/code_base/cvg_c*.cpp` will succeed. Is it a bug?

Comment: I'm not sure if PyCharm can resolve the asteriks (*) correctly?

Comment: @SimonFink Solved! This might be a TODO feature.