# python: add_argument for read data set but unable to read data folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, command-line-arguments

I am new with python and here I am practicing to understand the code by debugging.

python: add_argument for read data set but unable to read data folder.

Please check the attachment and below code.

```
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
## This is a useful line because it adds an option that we are interested in. The input file
ap.add_argument("-d", "--dataset", required=True,
    help="path to input dataset")
## The plot
ap.add_argument("-p", "--plot", type=str, default="plot.png",
    help="path to output loss/accuracy plot")
## The model
ap.add_argument("-m", "--model", type=str,
    default="mask_detector.model",
    help="path to output kite detector model")
## Parse the command line argument
args = vars(ap.parse_args())
```

Getting the error:

```
kite_detector.py: error: the following arguments are required: -d/--dataset
```

but the data with folder name **dataset** already exists in the project folder in which multiple classification folders.

please provide the link to understand and reason for the getting issue.
thanks in advance.[image]

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Comment: You should read about `argparse` and how to work with command line arguments in general. You are defining an `ArgumentParser` and by doing `parse_args` you are trying to read the command line arguments. The script can't *guess* that you want to use that folder

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pycharm and sys.argv arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33102272/pycharm-and-sys-argv-arguments) or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27952331/debugging-with-pycharm-terminal-arguments

Comment: @Tomerikoo It looks like issues in configuration and setup. I check with [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27952331/debugging-with-pycharm-terminal-arguments) but not getting the result or say not understand that solution, try that edit configuration but still facing the same issue.

Comment: Add a screenshot of your Run configurations please

Comment: @Tomerikoo please check ss attached in question.

Comment: what is that value? It makse no sense... Just put in the `Parameters` field something like `-d dataset`

Comment: @Tomerikoo yes, sorry i forgot to set the path of -d path of the dataset in the argument, and now its solved the error. thanks

Comment: Happy to hear :) Good luck!